# How can I rename files to have a single quote?

Tags: rename, file-management

I have multiple files on my Ubuntu system that are spread across web root folder `/var/www` with broken names:

```
GermanyXXXs-enchanting....
```

I want to replace XXX with an apostrophe ' to have the following output:

```
Germany's-enchanting....
```

The following command works with regular characters but not with quotes, even if I escape it:

```
find /var/www/html -name '*XXX*' -exec bash -c ' mv $0 ${0/XXX/\'}' {} \;
```

Comment: Please reconsider this. It will make everything you ever want to do with these files much, much harder. Is it really worth it?

Answer (score 3):

In Bourne-like shells, you can't have single quotes inside single quoted strings, they needs to be quoted some other way, whether that's with `\'`, `"'"`, `$'\''`...

Also remember that in `bash`, parameter expansions must be quoted with double quotes at least when in list contexts such as in arguments to commands.

When renaming recursively, you also need to make sure files are renamed *depth-first* and make sure you only rename the basename part of the file (not the directory components)

```
find /var/www/html -depth -name '*XXX*' -execdir bash -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    mv -- "$file" "${file/XXX/\'\''}" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' bash {} +
```

Here quoting `'` as `\'` outside of the `'...'`.

`$file` was quoted as `"$file"` as it's in list context to avoid split+glob. `$?` didn't need to be quoted as it's an assignment to a scalar (non-list/array) variable, though writing `ret="$?"` would not have harmed.

Beware `-execdir` (used here so that `$file` contains only the basename (possibly prefixed with `./` with some `find` implementations)) is a non-standard extension though is relatively widely supported these days.

With `-execdir cmd {} +` (`+` instead of `;`), some `find` implementations will try and call `cmd` with more than one file as argument when possible, but also and maybe more importantly that allows failures of `cmd` if any to be reported back in `find`'s exit status.

Or you can use specialised batch-renaming tools. For instance, if using zsh instead of bash, you could use its `zmv` autoloadable function:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(**/)(*XXX*)' '$1${2/XXX/'\''}'
```

Why takes all the above into account and also runs some sanity checks beforehand to avoid you losing data.

Beware it leaves hidden files alone. If you want them to be renamed, change it to:

```
zmv '(**/)(*XXX*)(#qD)' '$1${2/XXX/'\''}'
```

You can add the `-n` option to `zmv` for a dry-run.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes within a single quote pair can be escaped by closing the single quote, entering `\'`, then restarting the single quote pair

```
echo 'It isn't hard'     # broken
echo 'It isn'\''t hard'  # fixed
```

which turns one broken string into the three units `'It isn'` and `\'` and `'t hard'`. Another way to think about it: every `'` within a `'...'` single quote must be replaced with `'\''`.